# POSTMAN's response is different than python's response

Tags: python, get, python-requests, postman

I'm doing a GET request on POSTMAN. The request is just this URL `https://www.google.com/search?q=pip+google-images&tbm=isch` and I get a 853639 characters long response(Which is the response I want).
So I want to do the same thing with Python. I used the Postman's `GENERATE CODE SNIPPETS` and copied the code for `Python Requests`, I pasted it into my own python script and ran it.
But the response I got was only 22490 characters long(The response I don't want).
Why is it happening?

Python's code:

```py
import requests

url = "https://www.google.com/search"

querystring = {"q":"pip google-images","tbm":"isch"}

headers = {
    'cache-control': "no-cache",
    'postman-token': "6b5e997f-6651-2178-1371-5d6a555984a7"
    }

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)

print(response.text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the User-Agent, e.g.

```
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'
}
```

Include this in your headers.